# Type issue in components "has no properties in common with type IntrinsicAttributes & OptionBuilder" with `vue-facing-decorator`

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I have recently moved away from `vue-property-decorators` to [`vue-facing-decorators`](https://facing-dev.github.io/vue-facing-decorator/#/?id=information).

I have moved most of the components to use `vue-facing-decorators`.

I am seeing a lot of issues saying.

```
TS2559: Type { class: string[]; } has no properties in common with type IntrinsicAttributes & OptionBuilder
```

For instance, a function inside my component is using `VNode` to render something.

```js
import { VNode } from 'vue';
import { ActionBar } from '../action-bar';


@Component({
  components: {
    ...,
    ActionBar,
    ...,
  },
  directives: {
    ...,
  },
})
export default class ColorPicker extends ExtendedVue {


// method where this is passed.
return (
  <div class={[`${cssPrefix}__picker-cont`]}>
      <ActionBar class={['flexbox__flex-none']}> // this line has issue - TS2559: Type { class: string[]; } has no properties in common with type IntrinsicAttributes & OptionBuilder
      </ActionBar>
  </div>
) as VNode;
```

This is how ActionBar Component looks like.

```js
<template><!-- eslint-disable max-len -->
  <div :class="['action-bar', 'flexbox']">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component } from 'vue-facing-decorator';
import { ExtendedVue } from '../extended-vue';

@Component({})
export default class ActionBar extends ExtendedVue {
}
</script>
```

This is one of the many places where I am getting this error.

On research, I found these.
https://github.com/facing-dev/vue-facing-decorator/blob/master/src/optionBuilder.ts#L5
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#attribute-type-checking

Currently the ExtendedVue looks like this.

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-facing-decorator';
// import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

/* eslint max-classes-per-file: ["error", 2] */

/** used only in vue-shim.d.ts for typing */
export class ExtendedVueShim extends Vue {
  protected __attr_props__?: any; // eslint-disable-line
  [index: string]: any;
}

@Component({})
export class ExtendedVue extends Vue {
  protected __attr_props__?: any; // eslint-disable-line
}
```

In the above code, If I extend `vue` from `vue-property-decorator` I don't see any more type issues. I think there is some type issue with `vue` that is being imported here in `vue-facing-decorator`.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. It required me to bump up certain packages.

1. Typescript updated to `5.0.4` from `4.4.4`. This came along with setting `experimentalDecorators: true` as `false`. Using `stage 3` decorators.
2. Vue updated to latest `3.4.3`, because the same `no property` started to pop-up in `.tsx` files.

> Source worth looking at:
>
> 1. https://github.com/facing-dev/vue-facing-decorator/discussions/101
> 2. [Eslint error `is defined but never used` warning in NestJs for all decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73591752/eslint-error-is-defined-but-never-used-warning-in-nestjs-for-all-decorators)